# parameterisation of a set $M$. $ M = $ rotation of the image of a curve $c$ around x-axis.

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, rotations, curves

Let $ c : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ be a space curve with  $c(t) = (f(t),g(t),0)$.

if we rotate the image of $c$ around the x-axis, we get the set $R$.

> **First task:** Find a parameterisation of $R$. When is this parameterisation regular?
>
> **Second task:** Consider $c(t) = (\cos(t), 2 + \sin(t), 0)$ and make a sketch of the rotation around the x-axis.

So the **second task** was no problem. It is a torus.
So I only need help with the **first task**. My assumption is that the parameterisation is $X :(0,2\cdot \pi] \times I  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with $X(t,a) =$ $(f(t),g(t)\cos(a),g(t)\sin(a))$.Why? :  Because of the rotation  I think that we need polar coordinates $ r\cos(a)$ and $r\sin(a)$.  But to be honest: I don't know how I can explain the parameterisation above. It was just an ''idea'' . So if the parameterisation is right, I need help with the explanation. And if my parameterisation is false: Can you tell me where's my mistake?

For the second question of **first task** : $D_t(t,a) = ( f'(t), g'(t)\cos(a),g'(t)\sin(a)) $ and $D_a(t,a) = ( 0, -g(t)\sin(a),g(t)\cos(a)) $ has to be linearly independent. My thoughts here: first of all we need that $f,g$ are differentiable. Moreover $g(t) \neq 0 $. And if $f'(t) = 0$ we need that $ g'(t) \neq 0 $. And if $g'(t) = 0$ we need that $ f'(t) \neq 0 $, right? Do you see more problems?